# Moving contents of a cell with app script in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Image of the lines of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akf6Q.jpg)For something I've been working on, it involves moving an image from one cell to another through appscript or functions. I've tried to figure out ways to do this, but had no luck. Does anybody have any suggestions? For example, I would need to move an image on A11 to A34.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sample script 1:

About `For example, I would need to move an image on A11 to A34.`, if your image is put over the cell "A11", and you want to move it to the cell "A34", how about the following sample script?

```js
function sample1() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const fromCell = "A11";
  const toCell = "A34";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const image = sheet.getImages().filter(e => e.getAnchorCell().getA1Notation() == fromCell);
  if (image.length == 0) return;
  image[0].setAnchorCell(sheet.getRange(toCell));
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

About `For example, I would need to move an image on A11 to A34.`, if your image is put into the cell "A11", and you want to move it to the cell "A34", how about the following sample script?

```js
function sample2() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const fromCell = "A11";
  const toCell = "A34";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const srcRange = sheet.getRange(fromCell);
  srcRange.copyTo(sheet.getRange(toCell));
  srcRange.clearContent();
}
```

#### Note:

- From your reply and provided sample Spreadsheet, I could understand that your image of `I would need to move an image on A11 to A34.` is put into a cell instead of over the cell. In this case, I think that my 2nd script can be used. When I tested your provided sample Spreadsheet using my proposed 2nd script, no error occurs. The image in the cell "A11" is moved to the cell "A34".
- From your reply of `The second sample script, when I attempt to run it, I get the message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null".`, for example, as I mentioned `Please set the sheet name.`, if the sheet name of your tested Spreadsheet is not "Sheet1", such error occurs. If my understanding is correct, please modify `Sheet1` of `const sheetName = "Sheet1";` to your actual sheet name and test it again.

#### References:

- [getImages()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getimages)
- [setAnchorCell(cell)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image#setAnchorCell(Range))
- [copyTo(destination) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

Comment: Thank you for helping, however I've run into some issues. On the first sample script, the function comes up with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getImages' of null." The second sample script, when I attempt to run it, I get the message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null". If you are able to help, that would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: @user18597123 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `however I've run into some issues. On the first sample script, the function runs cleanly, however it doesn't change anything on the sheet. The second sample script, when I attempt to run it, I get the message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null".`, I think that in this case, it is required to confirm your sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating it. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I apologize as well, I don't really understand what you need. If it is the spreadsheet, the original contains a lot of information, so I created a sample with only an image from the web and text stating where it needs to go. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J9RvXlBoZL4yLs87DR2t0jJmdDBCQG5vPLBAu6P-WOc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user18597123 Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I could understand that your image of `I would need to move an image on A11 to A34.` is put into a cell instead of over the cell. In this case, when I tested your provided sample Spreadsheet using my proposed 2nd script, no error occurs. The image in the cell "A11" is moved to the cell "A34". So I cannot replicate your situation of `The second sample script, when I attempt to run it, I get the message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null".`.

Comment: @user18597123 For example, as I mentioned `Please set the sheet name.`, if the sheet name of your tested Spreadsheet is not "Sheet1", such error occurs. So I'm worried that you might not modify `const sheetName = "Sheet1";`. How about this?

Comment: @user18597123 By the way, it seems that at your provided sample Spreadsheet, the sheet name is "Sheet1". So in this case, my 2nd script can be directly used. When your actual sheet name is different from "Sheet1", please modify `Sheet1` of `const sheetName = "Sheet1";` and test it again.

Comment: I'm so sorry you're totally correct! I misunderstood and was putting the name of the whole sheet in my drive. Thank you so much, it works now!! Really appreciate it.