# How to move a Cell Image using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I get a cell in a cell and move into another file?

I'm trying something along below lines, like a dizzy cockroach, but unsuccessfull so far:

```
function moveOrders () {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const orderSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Orders');
const activeSheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
const thisRow = e.range.getRow();
const thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
const cellValue = e.range.getValue();
const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet31');

if (activeSheetName == orderSheet.getName() && thisRow > 5 && thisCol < 13 && cellValue == 'Confirmed') {
    const rowValues = orderSheet.getRange(thisRow, 1, 1, 13).getValues();
    const image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage(rowValues[2]).setAltTextDescription('Clothing Piece').toBuilder().build();
    destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet+1,1,rowValues.length, rowValues[0].length).setValues(rowValues)
}
```

This is how I get the value, the image being highlighted in green (3rd element of the array:
[image]

It throws the following error:
[image]

Parametes null don't correspond to method signatures for SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage

Here's a sample file for tests: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gxhXeNCMZ8MnJds1LM7vGQqibYgfXDYPkA6q6VNHcN0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newcellimage `SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage()` shouldn't have a parameter.

Comment: is the image in the cell? Can you share a copy or an example spreadsheet? Please remove sensitive data if there are any. Also see if this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287227/reposition-imagess-in-google-spreadsheet-using-script-gas

Comment: Just added it, @DanF! Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I thought that in your situation, this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71636160 How about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in your situation, this thread might be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71636160) And, if this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

And, from `const activeSheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();`, `const thisRow = e.range.getRow();` and so on, I guessed that you might want to use your script as the OnEdit trigger.

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const orderSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Orders');
  const activeSheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  const thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  const cellValue = e.range.getValue();
  const destinationSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet31');
  if (activeSheetName == orderSheet.getName() && thisRow > 5 && thisCol < 13 && cellValue == 'Confirmed') {
    const rowValues = orderSheet.getRange(thisRow, 1, 1, 13);
    rowValues.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
  }
}
```

- In your showing script, `destinationSheet+` of `destinationSheet+1` is Sheet object. In this case, an error occurs. I guessed that you might use `destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1`.
- When this script is run, the row is copied from "Orders" to "Sheet31" using `copyTo`. By this, the row including both the image and the values can be copied.

#### References:

- Related thread.

  - [Moving contents of a cell with app script in Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71636160)
- [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

### Added

About `Does this work between files, as well?`, when the above script is modified, it becomes as follows. In this case, please install the OnEdit trigger to `installedOnEdit`.

#### Sample script:

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID.

  const orderSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Orders');
  const activeSheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  const thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  const cellValue = e.range.getValue();
  if (activeSheetName == orderSheet.getName() && thisRow > 5 && thisCol < 13 && cellValue == 'Confirmed') {
    const dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstSpreadsheetId);
    const destinationSheet = dstSS.getSheetByName('Sheet31');
    const temp = orderSheet.copyTo(dstSS);
    const rowValues = temp.getRange(thisRow, 1, 1, 13);
    rowValues.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
    dstSS.deleteSheet(temp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Tanaike! Does this work between files, as well? If so, I understand that I'll have to set an installable trigger on edit basis for this function.

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. About `Does this work between files, as well?`, in this case, unfortunately, `copyTo` cannot be directly used between Spreadsheet A and Spreadsheet B. So in this case, as a workaround, first, a sheet is copied from Spreadsheet A to Spreadsheet B as a temporal sheet. Second, the row is copied from the temporal sheet. And then, remove the temporal sheet. By this, you can copy the row from Spreadsheet A to Spreadsheet B. Of course, in this case, please use the installable OnEdit trigger. If this explanation is not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you, Tanaike! This is exactly what I was after. Sorry I didn't mention that in my original question!

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. For copying the value from Spreadsheet A to Spreadsheet B, I added a sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I've read it carefully. Thank you very much! I'll implement it tomorrow!

Comment: thanks for great insights @Tanaike, have not thought of that alternative!

Comment: @santosOnit Thank you for replying. As a confirmation point of this script, before you use this script, please confirm whether you have the write permission to the destination Spreadsheet, again.

Comment: @Dan F In the current stage, `copyTo` of Class Range can be used in only the same Spreadsheet. I wish I could use it between different Spreadsheets in the future update.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use moveTo(), there's no need for getValues and setValues this will cut and paste both format and value from this range and target range.

Try this code instead:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const orderSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Orders');
  const activeSheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  const thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  const cellValue = e.range.getValue();
  const destinationSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Destination');
  if (activeSheetName == orderSheet.getName() && thisRow > 5 && thisCol < 13 && cellValue == 'Confirmed') {
    const rowValues = orderSheet.getRange(thisRow, 1, 1, 13);
    rowValues.moveTo(destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works!

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget

Comment: Thank you! Does this work between files, as well?

Comment: Do you mean from this spreadsheet to another spreadsheet? Sorry that won't work since the moveTo() only works on the same spreadsheet it cant really hold the value for it to be cut and pasted to another spreadsheet.

Comment: That's been so tricky, as this Cell Image API is recent, from what I've seen. Appreciate your time.